# NSTextView non-editable areas of text?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I have an `NSTextView` that contains data for the user to edit, but I want to surround it with a header and footer of non-editable data to give the user an idea of context.

I don't think an `NSTextView` can handle the concept of mixed editable/non-editable data, so I've come up with a few ideas.

a) Use text attachments with a custom cell to draw the header and footers.

b) Have 3 `NSTextView`s within the `NSScrollView`.

c) Use attributes to determine what cannot be edited,and use the delegate methods to prevent editing, this is probably my favourite, as it's probably the least intrusive.

Am I missing anything, any better ideas?

Answer (score 9):

The NSTextView delegate method [-textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextViewDelegate/textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:) will let you do this. You can "just say NO" to change. ;-)

**Update / Elaboration (November, 2015)**

To elaborate based on the comments on this answer, the idea is to use your own custom attributes on the [attributed string](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000036-BBCCGDBG) your text view is editing. Beyond the [standard attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004903-SW2), you can specify your own attribute name (any `NSString`) and [PLIST-compatible object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html) as the value for that name.

For example, if you wanted to designate a range of text as "uneditable", you could [add an attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/ChangingAttrStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000162-BBCBGCDG) for that range with an attribute named (for example) `@"TextIsEditableAttributeName"` with an `NSNumber` with a `BOOL` value of `YES` or `NO`: `[NSNumber NO]` or `@( NO )` (to use ObjC number boxing - same result: an NSNumber instance). Later, when the text view asks its delegate if it should change text in range, you can inspect the range for the presence of your `@"TextIsEditableAttributeName"` attribute.

Really, there's only a need to assign an attribute to ranges that *aren't* editable, so you don't even have to check for the value. You could just put an empty `NSData` instance there for a placeholder so the attribute has a value. Your attribute name could be `@"EditingLocked"` or something. This means you only have to check for the *presence* of the `@"EditingLocked"` attribute *anywhere in the proposed range* and return `NO` when the text view asks. This would catch overlapped selection (if you allow selection for copying the non-editable text) of editable vs. non-editable ranges.

This same approach, of course, can work for `-textView:willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRanges:toCharacterRanges:`, another delegate method that allows you to return a "corrected" array of *range values* for selection. If you don't want to allow non-editable text to be selected, you can "cut out" the ranges described by any instances of your `@"EditingLocked"` attribute you find in the proposed ranges.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The 'range' of the footer could change depending on the edits the user makes, so I guess I could use custom attributes to keep track.
I think this is sounding like the best approach so far...
Thanks for the comments.

Comment: That's a big part of what custom attributes are for. :-)

Comment: can you share how you were able to achieve assigning the custom attribute to keep track of the text(as the range changes).

Comment: @Ekra: Please read the documentation. A quick search of the Apple docs for "custom attribute" reveals several links to the text-related documentation. Reading all the text-system-related results will give you a solid footing. From there, ask more specific questions on SO if you have them.

Comment: Updated my answer with some elaboration. Though the original answer was given in '09 and my last comment was in '12, the approach is still valid (and, IMO, the absolute best with Cocoa's text system). I thought I'd flesh out the concept a bit more, though, since the question still gets votes.