# Non editable text inside editable NSTextview cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to insert some non-editable text inside the editable NSTextview.
You may consider like a footer in  iPhone mail app. as we insert new texts the footer will scroll down. (only exception is the user should not be able to edit the text in my case).

I have seen below link but it didn't help

[NSTextView non-editable areas of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750250/nstextview-non-editable-areas-of-text)

Any hint in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using delegate methods to just disable editing it that range?

Comment: As the user will type the text the range will change right ?

Comment: anyone can give some hint on the question

Comment: What about using a custom attribute to keep track of what's editable and what's not, as suggested in the linked answer's comments?